# Problems with Batch and "for" loop

Tags: batch-file

I have got following code

```
IF NOT EXIST d:\Ordner2\*.csv move /-Y d:\Ordner1\*.csv d:\Ordner2\fertig.csv
```

now I got a problem because in Ordner1 are more than one files. I have read something about a for loop but I don't now how and where to integrate. I would be very happy if someone could help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have more than one file in your source folder and (from your code) you need only one file in target. Which of the files in source folder should be moved to target folder?

Comment: In my target folder there should only be one file. With my code the batch tries to move all files from source file to target file. But only one should be picked.

Comment: `only one should be picked` so, which one should be picked? Is there any criteria to select the file?

Comment: There is a timestamp in the filename in Ordner1. Perhaps the oldest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this (havent had a chance to test)

```
if not exist d:\Ordner2\*.csv (
    for /f %%i in ('dir /b d:\Ordner1\*.csv') do ( move /-Y "d:\Ordner1\%%~i" d:\Ordner2 && goto done )
)
:done
```

if this is closer to what you were looking for, but still not accurate, please explain how it is lacking.

Comment: Thats great thanks a lot. Everything works now. Have a nice day